# Django Database Design Problem - Multiple App Single Database

Tags: django, database

I have two django applications using the same database. These applications have their own models. Since both applications use the same database, I can authorize with common users, I can use User model as foreign key for models.

Let's call these two django apps A and B. Because A and B use the same database, a user can be associated with models in both applications.

If a user is associated with a model in both applications, the user I deleted from application A cannot be deleted because it is associated with a model in application B.

I think I made a wrong design. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: **"the user I deleted from application A cannot be deleted because it is associated with a model in application B"** - if you're looking for deleting the whole entry related to `key` you can use `models.ForeignKey(..., on_delete=models.CASCADE)`. Additionally, [Relationship fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related) - this topic gives you some idea on _relationships_. **Cascade deletes**. Django emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint ON DELETE CASCADE and also deletes the object containing the ForeignKey.

Comment: Sorry for wording it wrong. "App" is not a django app but a completely separate django project. That's why the CASCADE definition is not enough. Because the two projects are independent of each other, they just use the same database. Their models are also different. Therefore, if the user we deleted in project A is associated with one of the models in project B,it gives an error

update or delete on table "auth_user" violates foreign key constraint "project_b_model_user_id_XXXX_fk_auth_user_id" on table "project_b_model"
DETAIL: Key (id)=(7) is still referenced from table "project_b_model".

Comment: If that DB resides in either App "A" or "B", and uses the same data structure then pull out the DB and run it as separate instance (e.g. docker instance) via docker-compose. So, migrating won't affect key constraint error. Lets, try it that way first. You can also build an _database-api_ & hit that url when any change is needed, there is library called [postgrest](https://postgrest.org/en/stable/index.html) see if it helps.